# Snchronous to Asynchronous method while keeping Synchronous method signiture

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have an application that Currently has the following structure

```
foreach (var req in requests)
{  
   var myReq = req;
   var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      var result = valueService.Calc(myReq);
      return result;
   }
   taskArray.Add(t)
   t.Start();
}

Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

Further on in my application i use the t.Result on every task.

Now this works well because my `Calc(myReq)` is a synchronous method.

However, now i have been given a requirement where my `valuationService.Calc(myReq)` will be calling an asynch method and the result will come back in a Callback method.

```
class ValuationService
{
   ....
   public MyResult Calc(MyRequest myReq)
   {
      obj.Callback = MyCallback;
      obj.CalcAsync()
   }

   public void Callback(MyResult result)
   {
     ...
   }
```

So what I want to achieve is : have valuationService.Calc(MyReq) keep its signature and somehow block until the callback method is run.  Then have the result of the callback be passed back to the Calc method so that it can pass back the data.

Comment: http://blog.tedd.no/2013/09/13/async-callback-to-awaitable-task/

Comment: I have no time to write a full answer, but the general idea is that you convert your callback methods to awaitable tasks, and use async/await inside `Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { ... } )`.

Comment: @Dorus You should not combine `StartNew()` with `async`, it leads to confusing `Task<Task>`.

Comment: Was `public void Callback(MyResult result)` supposed to be `public void MyCallback(MyResult result)`? Also can you change the internal code of `Calc` or is that class fixed?

Comment: @svick yeah probably, I know this stuff but the exact details are a little fuzzy unless I look it up, that's why I only gave a comment to sketch the general idea, feel free to add an answer with the correct methods :)

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that `Calc` keeps the exact same signature or would it be ok for it to return a `Task<MyResult>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what I want to achieve is : have valuationService.Calc(MyReq) keep its signature and somehow block until the callback method is run.

If that's what you *really want*, then you can do it with a simple `ManualResetEvent`:

```
public MyResult Calc(MyRequest myReq)
{
   var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
   obj.Callback = result => MyCallback(result, mre);
   obj.CalcAsync();
   mre.WaitOne();
}

public void Callback(MyResult result, ManualResetEvent mre)
{
  try
  {
    ...
  }
  finally
  {
    mre.Set();
  }
}
```

However, please be aware that now the code will use up a thread pool thread just to sit in the waiting state until the callback is called. This may impact your performance.

An alternative solution is to accept the nature of asynchronous work (i.e., not waste threads blocking on asynchronous operations). If you have both CPU-bound and asynchronous work, you can consider TPL Dataflow as one style of solution.

Comment: I'm happy with this answer.  Of course the Calc() will have a return statement to return the MyResult.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty trivial with `await`:

```
async Task DoAsync(Action callback)
{
  await WhateverAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

  callback();
}
```

You will want to ensure there's no exceptions in the callback, though - since the task is never awaited, they're going to be swallowed. Add custom error handling as needed.

If you don't have `await` available, you can do a similar thing with continuations:

```
WhateverAsync().ContinueWith(t => callback());
```

It just makes the error handling a bit tricker :)

The end result is that you have a `Task` that you can synchronously wait on if needed - which seems to be exactly what you're trying to do.

If you're not the one executing the callback, you'll want to use `TaskCompletionSource` to provide a `Task` of your own. In the callback method, you're going to use `tcs.SetResult(result)` (or `SetException`, if needed). The easiest way to do this is with a closure:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MyResult>();
obj.Callback = result => { doWhateverYouNeed(); tcs.SetResult(result); };

return tcs.Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: The question seems to be how to wait until a callback is called, not how to invoke the callback.